# How do I send imessages to non-iphone users on my macbook os x, if I don't have an iphone?

Tags: messages

How do I send imessages to non-iphone users on my macbook os x, if I don't have an iphone?

I have macosx so i can send imessages without an iphone currently and this works fine. But i also want to send messages to my family members, who don't have iphones.

Answer (score -1):

Create contacts for your non-iPhone users in Contacts.app, then iMessage should use SMS to connect. If you use iCloud Contacts, then they become available on all devices on which you use iCloud:

[image]

Below, an SMS conversation with a friend who has an Android phone, viewed on my Mac:

[image]

Comment: If the OP doesn't have an iPhone, by what mechanism will his Mac send SMS messages?

Comment: A down-vote for an answer 3 years old? If it is in error because the underlying mechanism has changed, or technology has progressed to solve the problem, then make an edit if you have enough reputation, or leave a comment.

Comment: @IconDaemon See first comment - how do you send the SMS message if you do not have an iPhone Apple's doc https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT202549 says "iPhone owners can use it for SMS and MMS messages, too.". Community raised the message to the front page to get it more views

Comment: Apologies. I accept your down vote.